# Do Overlapped I/O on Windows complete in FIFO?

Tags: winapi

When I issues a multiple Overlapped I/O on the same I/O handle. Do Windows complete the first request before doing the next request? Or the order is unpredictable?

If in the first case, What happen when error occurred on a request that being processed? Windows will do the next request? or it will cancel all outstanding requests?

Comment: The order is unpredictable. Each operation has its own error state. It is possible for one operation to fail, but another to succeed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx